# Python working with special character

Tags: python, url, unicode, encoding

I have this [TRADE MARK SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) character (u"\u2122").

1) How can I print this character in the **terminal** without *UnicodeEncodeError*.

2) I want to open chrome with a specific url and in the url there is this special character. Now normally open chrome with specific url like this:

```
import os
url = "some-kind-of-url-with-™"
os.system("start chrome " + url)
```

but I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 67: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How should I open chrome with a specific url and in the url there is this special character ™

Comment: URLs have very specific encoding requirements. Normally your browser does this for you when you use the location bar, but for use on a command line you need to do so yourself.

Comment: Like this? [`http://www.example.com/%e2%84%a2`](http://www.example.com/%e2%84%a2) You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thank you @PM2Ring really much. That is what I was searching for. It's not that professional solution but I like the simplicity.